# How to determine which derived class is being pointed to when using an array of pointers

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I am writing a C++ program that will roll a die and flip a coin.  I need to use inheritance and polymorphism.  I have my virtual functions set up correctly.  In my base class(aRandomNumberGenerator) I have a virtual function generate.  In main() I need to have an array of 2 base class pointers to my derived classes(aDie and aCoin).  How do I know which derived class is being pointed to in the array when I call the generate() function??

code:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    int frequency1 = 0; // count of 1s rolled
    int frequency2 = 0; // count of 2s rolled
    int frequency3 = 0; // count of 3s rolled
    int frequency4 = 0; // count of 4s rolled
    int frequency5 = 0; // count of 5s rolled
    int frequency6 = 0; // count of 6s rolled
    int face; // stores most recently rolled value
    int numHeads = 0; // count of heads
    int numTails = 0; // count of tails
    int side; // stores most recently flipped value

    cout << "Enter a seed number: "; // promp for user to enter a seed number
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    aRandomNumberGenerator number(n);
    aDie die(n, n);
    aCoin coin(n, n);

    aRandomNumberGenerator *games[2]; // array of 2 base class pointers

    for(int i=0; i <= 2; i++)  
      games[i]->generate();  


    // output the seed number entered by the user
    cout << "the seed entered is: " << die.inputSeed(n) << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    // summarize results for 600 flips of a coin
    for(int counter2 = 0; counter2 < 600; counter2++)
    {
        side = generate();

        // determine flip value 0/1 and increment appropriate counter
        switch ( side )
        {
        case 0:
            ++numHeads;
            break;
        case 1:
            ++numTails;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "can only be heads or tails";
        }
    }

    // summarize results for 600 rolls of a die
    for(int counter1 = 0; counter1 < 600; counter1++)
    {
        face = generate();

        // determine roll value 1-6 and increment appropriate counter
        switch ( face )
        {
        case 1:
            ++frequency1;
            break;
        case 2:
            ++frequency2;
            break;
        case 3:
            ++frequency3;
            break;
        case 4:
            ++frequency4;
            break;
        case 5:
            ++frequency5;
            break;
        case 6:
            ++frequency6;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "7 doen't exist on a die!";
        }
    }

    // output results
    cout << "Heads: " << numHeads << endl;
    cout << "Tails: " << numTails << endl;
    cout << "1: " << frequency1 << endl;
    cout << "2: " << frequency2 << endl;
    cout << "3: " << frequency3 << endl;
    cout << "4: " << frequency4 << endl;
    cout << "5: " << frequency5 << endl;
    cout << "6: " << frequency6 << endl;

    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
```

Comment: The whole point of.using polymorphism is that hou don't have to.worry about the type at all

Answer (score 8):

Use dynamic_cast.

```
if (Derived1* ptr = dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(basepointer)) {
    // Do something with ptr
}
```

However for a regular method call you don't need to determine it. Just call the method on the base class and it'll be dispatched to the correct derived class- that's what inheritance is for.

Edit: For a regular *virtual* method, you can just call it on the base pointer and don't know or care what the Derived is, and you'll get the right function call.

Answer (score 3):

```
aRandomNumberGenerator *games[2]; // array of 2 base class pointers 

for(int i=0; i <= 2; i++)   
  games[i]->generate();
```

First, let's get it working before we deal with other things.

You are creating an array which will hold pointers to two aRandomNumberGenerator objects, but you never create the aRandomNumberGenerator objects themselves.  `games[0]` and `games[1]` hold meaningless values.   Further, in the loop, you also access `games[2]` which doesn't exist.

UPDATE:
For some reason, the other answerer, decided to use the bizarre shorthand version of the code, which I hate, and would probably confuse any inexperienced C++ code (which the OP clearly is), so let's do that ourselves:

```
Derived1* ptr = dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(basepointer)
if (ptr != null) 
{ 
    // Do something with ptr 
}
```

Comment: I fixed my for loop, do I need to create each object like normal objects? and also what is the dynamic_cast code for?

ex.  aRandomNumberGenerator games[0] = &aCoin
     aRandomNumberGenerator games[1] = &aDie

Comment: I used the shortened version because it ensures that ptr is never misused if it's not a Derived1. If the OP is not an experienced C++ coder, this is an additional level of protection.

Answer (score 0):

You could use RTTI (typeid and dynamic_cast), or add a virtual function that, in the implementation, identifies the class (rolling your own RTTI).

Generally, if you can avoid it, it is considered bad practice to add implementation-dependent code (code that cares what the exact type is) except for in the implementation itself.  By "implementation", I don't just mean the specific derives class, I also mean paired/related classes that are specific to that implementation.

Try to roll the switch/else-if statements that are specific to your exact implementations into the implementations themselves, via polymorphism.

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.6